# Dynamically created CheckBoxs fires on second click instead first

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, dynamically-generated

I have created CheckBoxs dynamically in GridView but the CheckedChanged event fires when I click the twice.

Where I'am wrong?

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // check if it's not a header and footer
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Row)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();

        chk.AutoPostBack = true;

        // add checked changed event to checkboxes
        chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chk_CheckedChanged);

        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(chk); // add checkbox to second column
    }
}
```

Comment: Does giving the Checked field an initial value change anything?  ie: chk.Checked = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use below code in both `OnRowCreated` and `OnRowDataBound` events of GridView.

This will trigger the `CheckedChanged` only in first click.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    CheckBox chk = e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("chk") as CheckBox;
    if (chk == null)
    {
        chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.ID = "CheckBox1";
        chk.AutoPostBack = true;
        chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chk_CheckedChanged);

        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(chk);
    }
}
```